# Poor images on Stack Overflow's help page

Tags: bug, design, help-center

Reading the [moderator tools privillage page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), I came accross these very poor and unprofessional images. Just thought SO should know. I'd be happy to provide high quality Photoshopped screen shots if you need them, just let me know :)

**Image 1:**
[image]

---

**Image 2:** (I think the bottom one is glitchy, isn't it?)

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/140505

Comment: @Oded? What does that have to do with it? The screenshots I provided are not my design, they are from SO itlself...

Comment: And your issue with them is? I am assuming it is the freehand red circles. If that's not it, I am at a loss, because what you posted here are not the actual images from the help center and you have not specified an actual concrete problem with them ("very poor and unprofessional" is not particularly descriptive).

Comment: @Oded *" what you posted here are not the actual images from the help center"* - Yes they are !

Comment: Top one is, second one is not. The second one is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M36io.png - the one you posted is https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO0L5.png

Comment: @oded I'm sorry but both are! I'm not making anything up... Take a look

Comment: What you posted are screen shots you have made from the actual images.

Comment: Which is, again, besides the point. What is the actual, concrete issue you have with the images? What is "unprofessional" and "very poor" about them?

Comment: @Oded I snappedshot both images with their context to display them in my question. Still - the 2nd image is cropped and both look bad.

Comment: Define "look bad". What *exactly* do you mean? What's the specific issue (I can't fix "look bad" - I *can* fix "low resolution").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147165/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-oded).

Comment: Those images are pure professionalism IMO, freehand and everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have changed the images (to remove cut-off text), though I kept the free hand circles. This also had the side-effect of making them up-to-date with the current design.

I have also made them stand out a bit more from the page background.

Hope this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks Oded! Though why my post got so many downvotes is beyond me. I guess people don't like criticism after all.

Comment: @KobyDouek - likely people didn't understand your specific issues with the images, making this question "unclear".

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see here is the clipped text in the middle of image # 2.  If we remove it that gives us

[image: image of image #2 without question text in the screenshot]

Which I think looks better (maybe cut out some of the white space in the middle to condense it a little).

As far as the freehand circles and arrows are concerned that is a part of Stack Overflow and I love we use them in help.